# Does kotlin have command that is equivalent to golang `go mod init projectname`, and `go get packagelink`?

Tags: kotlin

My goal is to make a `WebSocketListener` from `okhttp3`. The problem is that I only know how to make the project using **IntelliJ IDEA CE**. Consequently, there are many boilerplates such as `.gradle`, `.idea`, `bin`, `build`, `gradle`, and so on.

Does kotlin have command that is equivalent to golang `go mod init projectname`, and `go get packagelink`?

Comment: Are you asking how Kotlin projects manage dependencies? There are basically two options: [Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html) or [Maven](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/maven.html). IntelliJ has a [create new project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-your-first-kotlin-app.html#create-project) helper for initialising either of these.

Comment: Kotlin provide a low-level compiler. But, 99.999% of projects use either Gradle or maven to maintain a cohesive build project. Now, If you use gradle, you will have .gradle, gradle, build.gradle(.kts?) files in your project. They are the minimal requirements to maintain the build. As for `build` dir, it is also required, it is where gradle will put compiled files. And finally, .idea directory will always be created, as long as you open you project with intellij. In the case of IntelliJ directory, you can put it in .gitignore to avoid pushing it online.